# Selecting last child using :last-child

Tags: jquery, css

Here is a simple HTML:

```
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="m1">
            <div id="m11"></div>
            <div id="m12"></div>
            <div id="m13"></div>
            <div id="m14"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I expect the following JQuery to change the content of div with id m14 to be "Hello". It is not.

```
  $('#outer #m1:last-child').html("Hello");
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: maybe `#outer#m1:last-child`

Comment: add a space .... `#outer #m1 :last-child`

Comment: you are now selecting `#outer`s last `#m1`  insted of `#m1` last div.  eg `  `$('#outer #m1 div:last-child').html("Hello");`

Comment: $('#outer #m1 div:last-child').html("Hello");

Comment: @mocni_T  Yes I missed this basic one... you are right. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.